# Beginner issue with random.choice

Tags: python, random

I want to create a list of students for each class, and then be able to randomly select a student.

```py
import random

period1 = ['bern', 'brian', 'molly', 'pizza', 'dave', 'deena', 'tom', 'kelly']

period2 = ['bob', 'shane', 'marge', 'frank', 'Becky ', 'Delilah ', 'Teddy', 'Hudson']

random_student = input('Which class needs a volunteer?')

print(random.choice(random_student))
```

Comment: What are you entering for `random_student`?

Comment: Are you trying to use the input to select either the variable `period1` or `period2`?

Comment: I was hoping to have a separate list that contains all of the students for each class.  For the input I enter either ‘period1’ or ‘period2’ but instead of printing a random student, I get one of the characters from ‘period1’ or ‘period2’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will be better off creating a dictionary rather than using lists.

```
 import random

period1 = ['bern', 'brian', 'molly', 'pizza', 'dave', 'deena', 'tom', 'kelly']

period2 = ['bob', 'shane', 'marge', 'frank', 'Becky ', 'Delilah ', 'Teddy', 'Hudson']

random_student = input('Which class needs a volunteer?')

d = {'period1': period1, 'period2': period2}

print(random.choice(d[random_student]))
```

`input` returns a string and not a variable. For example input will return `'period1'` as a string while you want to call the variable `period1` One way to get around this is to create a dictionary using a key and value pair. The key will be a string: `'period1'` and the values will be a list of student names. Now you will be able to filter to the list you want with a string.